# String Class Manipulation

Tags: c++

Is it possible to fix size of string variable. For example I want string variable `str_new` of capacity 5. P.S: I don't want to use `char str_new[5]`. I want to use `string` class. So the variable declaration should not use keyword `char`. Is this possible?

EXAMPLE: `string str_new;`

Is there any way to make sure that `str_new` size is fixed as `5`. This question might be absurd. Please enlighten.

This code throws exception just after execution of one iteration of 'for' loop. There might be better ways to copy one string to another. But I want to copy it as mentioned below. Can someone tell me how to fix the bug, or below code cannot be fixed as its totally messed up?

```
string str_old = "abcde";
        string str_new;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            str_new[i]= str_old[i];
        }
```

However This code works fine if I do following changes

```
string str_new = "     ";
```

So do I really need to explicitly initialize with blank spaces. Or there can be any other way.

Comment: Will the string change? (The content not the size)

Comment: I want to copy one string which is of size 5 to another new string str. And I want my new string str to be of exactly size 5.

Comment: `std::string` offers no (non-complex) way to fix the size.  There are ways, but they're absurdly complex and don't really work all that well.

Comment: You want to fix size or capacity ? if size, with which content; else see `std::string::reserve`.

Comment: Why do you want to fix the size?  `std::string` uses a dynamic sizing method, which is better 99.999% of the time.

Comment: is this what you mean? `string s="123456";s.resize(5);`

Comment: The answer is no, but depending on your needs a `std::array<char, 5>` might suffice? (Yes I know it uses char).

Comment: Why in the name of Jah would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking two questions, and this sound very much like a homework question.

> Is it possible to fix size of string variable.

There isn't any reasonable way to fix the size of a string to a size of X, and I can't think of any possible reason why you would even want to try to do so. That said, if there really is some business/homework rule that requires this, then simply check the size of the string before putting anything into it, if the size of the string plus the size of what you plan on inserting is over '5', then do something else.

For enlightenment on why, read up on the "zero one infinity rule".

> This code throws exception just after execution of one iteration of 'for' loop. There might be better ways to copy one string to another.

Your code throws an exception because you are trying to replace the first character of `str_new` with a different character, but your object doesn't have a first character to replace.

> But I want to copy it as mentioned below. Can someone tell me how to fix the bug, or below code cannot be fixed as its totally messed up?

Why do you want to use that for loop? That again leads me to believe this is some sort of homework assignment, because this is definitely *not* a good way to copy one string into another. A simple assignment is all that is necessary:

```
string str_new = str_old;
```

But I get it, you want to use the for loop and you don't even want a loop based on the actual size of `str_old`. Here you go:

```
string str_old = "abcde";
string str_new(5, 0);
assert(str_old.size() >= 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    str_new[i]= str_old[i];
}
```

The above code creates a string `str_new` that has five elements in it that are all equal to 0. It then checks to make sure that `str_old` actually is 5 characters long. Then it replaces each 0 with a copy of the character at the corresponding position in `str_old`.

Don't put that kind of code in a real program, but if it satisfies the homework assignment, then go for it.

Comment: Its not a homework assignment. I was just exploring if we can do it the way I mentioned above. I am solving "Cracking Coding Interview" by Gaylee Laakmann. And trying to solve each question in 5-6 methods to cover all grounds and this question was subpart of one of the question mentioned in the book. Anyways Thanks a ton for the detailed reply. Appreciate it !

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. If I had to come up with several different ways to copy one string to another, I would probably think of this one as an option. Another interesting method would be to use strcpy. As I recall, the standard was changed to make string hold contiguous memory so strcpy is an option.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do

```
string.reserve()
```

If you want initialized a string of the right capacity, you can do

```
string.resize()


void resize (size_t n);
void resize (size_t n, char c);
```

Resize string
Resizes the string to a length of n characters.

```
void reserve (size_t n = 0);
```

Request a change in capacity
Requests that the string capacity be adapted to a planned change in size to a length of up to n characters.

If n is greater than the current string capacity, the function causes the container to increase its capacity to n characters (or greater).

Comment: You're mixing terminology. `reserve` has to do with capacity, not `resize`.